# How to use pinky to just display users first name instead of all info Bash?

Tags: bash

```
#if argument passed in cannot be found among sessions logged in
function fname(){
result=$(pinky "$1")
if [ ! -f "$result" ] then
       FNAME="NOTFOUND"
return 0
else
       FNAME="$(pinky -f -h)"
return 0
fi
}
```

any ideas would be great, thanks! I tried to search online but could not find any useful suggestions, also, how do I check whether the input can be found, is the one I am having right now valid?

Comment: What does the argument represent?  The user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this.  I don't know what your `$1` argument represents.  If I had to guess, it is the login name.  Here is some example output of `pinky`:

```
Login    Name                 TTY      Idle   When             Where
fbar     Foo Bar              pts/0    00:26  2020-02-05 09:32 10.0.0.2
bbaz     Bar Baz              pts/1    00:03  2020-01-27 10:41 10.0.0.3
```

On the assumption that $1 will represent a login name, the following should work:

```
login_name=$1
pinky | awk -F '[ ]+' "\$1 == \"$login_name\" {print \$2}"
```

Explanation:

awk's `-F` option defines a field separator and supports regex.  So we are defining our separator as "at least 1 space" because the output of pinky is like a column type format where there could be multiple spaces between each field.  Using this as the field separator, the field values for user fbar will be as follows:

```
$1: fbar
$2: Foo
$3: Bar
$4: pts/0
... We don't really care about the rest.  We got the first name field ($2)
```

The actual awk code portion is `"\$1 == \"$login_name\" {print \$2}"`.  Normally, it is better to use single quotes for awk code to avoid all the escaping, but I want to include a bash variable, so I used double quotes.

`"\$1 == \"$login_name\"`  The `\$1` is referencing the first field in the input.  We are comparing that to our bash variable `$login_name` in a string comparison.  We could have left the bash variable as `$1`, but makes the comparison a bit more confusing (comparing `\$1` to `$1`).  If that the comparison is true, we run the next bit of code: `{print \$2}` This will print our first name field.

**Note:** If you have a user logged in with multiple sessions, you are going to get multiple lines of output.  If this is undesirable, you can also exit the awk program on the first match:

```
pinky | awk -F '[ ]+' "\$1 == \"$login_name\" {print \$2; exit}"
```

Another method that may be cleaner would be to use awk's `-v` (variable assignment) option to avoid the bash variable and escape characters:

```
pinky | awk -v login="$1" -F '[ ]+' '$1 == login {print $2; exit}'
```

**EDIT:**
The default field separator for `awk` is actually `[:space:]+` which is close to what I defined but includes other white space like tabs.  This makes the -F option above redundant and can be left out.

Comment: thanks! my input is the username, and I achieve the same effect using pinky -f (usrname) | awk '{print $2}'!! Thanks for your hint!

Comment: @YangZiqi Oh yea, that is a lot cleaner.  You taught me something new as well.  The default delimiter for awk is very close to what I defined, making the field separator definition redundant.